# Does the JVM use system calls to seek OS functionalities?

Tags: java, jvm

We know that the JVM calls on the underlying system to allocate memory and CPU time, access files, and many more. How does it work internally to achieve its activities?

Does the JVM use system calls?

Comment: What would the alternative be, if not "system calls"?

Comment: You are asking for a tautology. When you “know that the JVM calls on the underlying system”, you know that “the JVM use system calls”.

Answer (score 9):

> Does the JVM use system calls?

Yes.

> How does it work internally to achieve its activities?

The typical pattern is that some of the methods in a Java class are labelled as `native`.  When the JVM encounters a call to a `native` method it makes a call into C or C++ code that is part of the JVM executable.  The native method implementation typically does the following:

1. Check arguments from Java, and translates them into a C / C++ compatible form.  For example, `String` arguments need to be converted to zero-terminated form.
2. Call the standard C / C++ library function with the arguments it needs.
3. The library function makes the syscall.
4. The OS does its stuff and the syscall returns.
5. The standard C / C++ library function returns.
6. The native method implementation checks the 'errno'.  If there was an error, it creates a Java exception object and throws it.
7. Otherwise, the native method implementation converts results, etc into Java objects and returns them to the caller of the Java method.

The details vary, depending on what the native method does.

If you want to get a deeper understanding, I recommend that you checkout a copy of the OpenJDK source tree and start trawling.  (You need to do the hard yards yourself ....)

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, JVM needs to leverage system calls which is an operating system way to allow processes to interact with underlying system resources.

You can run `strace java -version` to see a bunch of system calls (`mmap`, `mprotect`, `openat`, etc.) executed even during this very limited java/jvm run.

Another good way to find out more is to dig trough JVM sources for native methods.
One example could be an implementation of [FileChannel#force method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#force(boolean))
which internally calls `fsync` system call (for example): https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/blob/5f01925b80ed851b133ee26fbcb07026ac04149e/src/java.base/unix/native/libnio/ch/FileDispatcherImpl.c#L172

Answer (score -3):

Yes, system calls are the only way that an OS allows access to any program.

In the case of Java, this is why some OS-specific “features” show through, so spoiling the ideal of write-once-run-anywhere.  For example, I’ve had a program that I developed on a Windows box fail when run on a Linux box.

The problem turned out to be that in the resources directory, the filename was all-lower case, but my program had the file name inMixed case.   The program worked on windows since filenames on windows are case-insensitive, but in Linux they are case-sensitive.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with system calls - it's just different file naming rules that apply to different systems.